# Father duck swim along $y=-x^2$,baby duck swim along $y=x^2$, Father duck’s movements parameterized by: $()=(−5,−(−5)^2)$, equation for baby?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

A father duck and a baby duck are swimming along opposing parabolic paths, with the father along $ = −^2$ and the baby along  = $^2$. The father duck’s movements can be parameterized by: $_() = ( − 5, −( − 5)^2), 0 \le  \le 5$ and he is always looking directly forward (along his path). The baby duck is trying to always stay exactly in front of her father. Find a parameterization of her path.

At the moment I don't even know what is the question is asking, I'm thinking like the baby duck is always ahead of the father duck as moving in the point along the tangent of the father duck at any time, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track! However, you should not put the main part of your question in a picture or a link.

Comment: You don't need to *show* this. It is given as a condition.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the tangent line? Do you know how to compute the intersections of a line with a parabola?

Comment: If the father duck traverses his parabola from left to right, then between times t=0 and t=5 (but not at exactly 5) the line of sight of the father will go from where the father is and up at an angle and will cross the upper parabola at a certain point, which is where the baby should be at that time. [at the time exactly t=5 the father will be at (0,0) which is a point on the baby's possible path, so the baby should be there at that time, however this is an odd situation where the baby and father are at the same place at the same time.]

Comment: @coffeemath, let's just assume that father and baby ducks have opposite spins.

Comment: @Ennar Indeed. :-) and ducks do like to spin.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line from the position of the father duck is

$ P(t, s) = ( t - 5, - (t - 5)^2 ) + s ( 1, - 2 (t - 5) ) $

This line intersects the parabola of the baby duck at

$ ( t - 5 + s)^2 = - (t - 5)^2 - 2 s (t - 5) $

Let $t' = t - 5 \le 0 $, then

$ (t' + s)^2 = - t'^2 - 2 s t' $

which gives us

$ t'^2 + 2 s t' + s^2 = - t'^2 - 2 s t' $

and this simplifies to

$ s^2 + 4 s t' + 2 t'^2 = 0 $

The solution of which is

$ s = \dfrac{ - 4 t' \pm \sqrt{ 8 t'^2 } } {2} = -2 t' \pm \sqrt{2} | t' | = t' ( - 2 \mp \sqrt{2} )   $

But $t' = t- 5 $ , therefore,

$ s = (5 - t) (2 \pm \sqrt{2} ) $

Substitute this into the equation $P(t,s)$

$ B(t) = ( t - 5, - (t - 5)^2 ) + (5 - t) (2 + \sqrt{2}) (1, -2 (t - 5) ) $

OR

$ B(t) = ( t - 5, - (t - 5)^2 ) + (5 - t) (2 - \sqrt{2}) (1, -2 (t - 5) ) $

These are the possible parametric equations for the paths for the baby duck.

Comment: Just replace $t - 5$ with $t'$

Answer (score 1):

The tangent line of the father duck's path
$$r_1(t)=(t-5,-(t-5)^2)$$
at time $t$ has slope
$$m=\left.(-x^2)'\right\vert_{x=t-5}=-2(t-5).$$
So, the tangent line is
$$\frac{y-(-(t-5)^2)}{x-(t-5)}=-2(t-5)$$
that is
$$y=-2(t-5)x+(t-5)^2.$$
Intersecting the tangent line with baby duck's swimming curve $y=x^2$ gives the quadratic equation
$$x^2+2(t-5)x-(t-5)^2=0.$$
Solution of this equation
$$x_{1,2}=(-1\pm\sqrt2)(t-5)$$
are the two possible $x$-coordinates of the baby duck's path. Hence the possible paths of the baby duck are
$$\small r_2(t)=((-1+\sqrt2)(t-5),
(3-2\sqrt2)(t-5)^2
)$$
and
$$\small r_2(t)=((-1-\sqrt2)(t-5),
(3+2\sqrt2)(t-5)^2
).$$

Comment: @HosamH I already used prime for derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Since the father duck is moving along the $y = -x^2$, we can look at the tangent line at $(x_0,-x_0^2)$:
$$y-(-x_0^2)=y'(x_0)(x-x_0)\implies y = -2x_0x+x_0^2.$$
Its intersections with $y = x^2$ are given by the solutions of $x^2=-2x_0x+x_0^2$ which are $$x_{1,2} = (-1\pm\sqrt 2)x_0,\\ y_{1,2} = x_{1,2}^2 =(3\mp2\sqrt 2)x_0^2.$$
Finally, we know that $x_0(t) = t-5$, so the baby duck's path is given by parametrizations
$$b_{1,2}(t)=((-1\pm\sqrt 2)(t-5),(3\mp2\sqrt 2)(t-5)^2),\ t\in[0,5].$$